# Address module PHP error due to missing interface

Tags: 8, commerce

I've installed the Address module and run Composer. I've checked the CommerceGuys/Addressing dependency is present. This was working fine, until a recent update (I'm not sure whether it was Drupal 8.2 or Address beta 4), but now the site is giving the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'CommerceGuys\\Addressing\\Model\\AddressFormatInterface' not found in /var/www/drupal/sites8/all/modules/address/src/Entity/AddressFormatInterface.php on line 16, referer: https://www.google.com/
```

Can anyone halp?

James

Comment: Sounds like you updated Address outside of Composer, which lead to it getting out of sync with the underlying library. "composer update drupal/address --with-dependencies" is how you update Address (or any other Drupal module). Running it now should fix your error.

Comment: Thanks for this! Seems to have worked. Will post longer response as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command Bojan offered above did the trick:

```
composer update drupal/address --with-dependencies
```

This gave the following message:

```
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

However, the site now displays correctly and doesn't log the message posted above.

Since it didn't seem to install anything, I presume it was the Autoload files that were the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I also needed to restart Apache, probably because Apcu had cached this

Answer (score 2):

If you update Drupal 8 with `drush`, and not composer, this will re-install the required address libraries:

```
composer require drupal/address
```

run in the Drupal root directory.