# Composer error installing Address module

Tags: 8, composer

I had a previous error with the Address module, [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/217814/address-module-php-error-due-to-missing-interface/218135#218135). Unfortunately the solution is no longer helping.

I'm installing the Address module as follows:

```
composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8
composer require "drupal/address ~1.0"
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package commerceguys/addressing (locked at v0.8.4, required as ~1.0) is satisfiable by commerceguys/addressing[v0.8.4] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package commerceguys/zone (locked at v0.7.1, required as ~1.0) is satisfiable by commerceguys/zone[v0.7.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

I've tried the solution linked above, but it doesn't help. I've also checked I'm running the latest version of Composer (1.2.1).

Any ideas?

James

Comment: The error message says the locked version is lower than the version you are requiring. I would try removing the composer.lock file, and running `composer require "drupal/address ~1.0"`. Keep in mind that you could get some problems, with packages.drupal.org. I tried using it for a local site, and the modules with dependencies ended up to be installed on the vendor directory, instead of the modules directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that I had installed a previous version of the Address module in the `sites/all/modules` directory, which seems to have been confusing Composer. Composer installs into the `modules` directory, and after deleting the older copy, I was able to run the `composer require` command without problems.